# how to add layout when we touch the screen in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, touch

I have the requirement that, I need to display my layout(with `EditText` and `Textview`) wherever user touches the screen. So I need to do something like below.

1. How to write customized layout with one `TextView` and `EditText`
2. Show the mylayout as many times user  touches the screen.
3. Set the layout parameters near to touch area.

..

```
public class MyLayout extends LinearLayout {
 private TextView myTextView;
 private EditText editName;
public MyLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);

    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```

}

MyActivity.java(whre i need to display my layout)

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);
     }

  @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
    {
       // here i need to display my layout
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In onTouch Method... do the following..

1. get your layout by id for e.g

   `RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativelayout)`
2. create new `edittext` and whatever you want.
3. add these in `relativeLayout`.

hope this clears.